# How to retrieve and read items from sharepoint list and assign them to a variable with JavaScript?

Tags: development, javascript

I have the following list

[image]
how can i retrive the value of koha column for first row and second row separate, datatype for koha column is number and how to assign value of koha into a variable `var result`
how can i do that in JavaScript?

Comment: It all depends on what you want to do with it....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Screenshot seems your environment is SharePoint 2013. So you can accomplish it using *REST API*.

Getting the value of koha column for first row

```
/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('ListName')/Items?$select=koha&$top=1
```

Make a HTTP GET request in the above URL. Now assign the value into `result` inside success callback.

- `$select`: which columns you wish to see in result.
- `$top`: how many rows

If you need only the values of `koha` column, then ignore `$top=1`.

```
/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('ListName')/Items?$select=koha
```

If you are using jQuery, then you can write your code like following

```
function getItems(url) {
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + url,
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {
            var result = data.d.result;
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });
}
```

Now call it like following

```
var url = "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('ListName')/Items?$select=koha&$top=1"
getItems(url);
```

If you are interested to understand the whole thing, then have a look on my article.

[CRUD Operation to List Using SharePoint 2013 Rest API](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/990131/CRUD-Operation-to-List-Using-SharePoint-Rest-API)

Comment: in you article i am referring  to GET Items From List where this `/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('ListName')/Items?$select=koha&$top=1` goes I am new to SP development so thank you

Comment: you can call it using jQuery. In my article, there is example

Comment: Find an update or have a look on my whole article. @NderonHyseni

Comment: how can we contact I need something from you? i can pay you!

Comment: ok i added you to my skype at night we talk or at sunday

Answer (score 3):

Once the listview has loaded all the info is in the ''ctx.ListData.row'' array so no need for REST or JSOM code

A quick and easy way is to hide that listview and do whatever you want with the data sharepoint loaded for you in the listview

Another option is to use CSR client side rendering, and get the value from ''ctx.CurrentItem.value''

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get a single item, you need the ID then you can use JSOM

```
getListItem = function(siteURL, listNameSTR, itemID)
{
    var ctxOBJ = new SP.ClientContext(siteURL);
    var listOBJ = ctxOBJ.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listNameSTR);
    var itemOBJ = listOBJ.getItemById(itemID);
    return itemOBJ; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My preferred way would be to use Client Side Rendering.

The code below will give you an array `result` that contains values of the `koha` field for all items in the current view.

```
var result = [];

SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", CSR_Setup);

function CSR_Setup() {
    var overridectx = {};
    overridectx.Templates = {};
    overridectx.Templates.Fields = {
        "koha": { "View": GetFieldVals }
    };
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overridectx); 
}

function GetFieldVals(ctx) {
    var fieldVal = ctx.CurrentItem[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name];
    result.push(fieldVal);
    return fieldVal;
}
```

Note the field name `koha` in the `CSR_Setup` function needs to be the *internal* name of the field.

Then iterate over the `result` array like so:

```
for (int i=0; i<result.length; i++) {
    alert(result[i]);
}
```

Comment: so now result has both values 30 and 25?

Comment: Yep `result` is an array with both values. Then iterate over the array in the normal fashion with a loop. I've updated my answer.